# Phonegap and Jquery Mobile input number with text placeholder

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a a input type "number" that I need placeholders to be: DD for day, MM for Month and YYYY for year. In Chrome, it does show the placeholder, but if I try input="number" and placeholder="DD" it shows the field empty when I run it on my Android device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Older WebKit didn't support placeholder for type=number.

Comment: Meaning Android Chrome is older? or compiling it with phonegap uses something "older"?